# Creating a calculated column (with an If statement) in Python using a dataframe extracted from Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe

fairly new to `Python` and I am trying to create a calculated column on my `DataFrame` using an If function.

I've tried using the fields directly referenced from the `DataFrame`, as well as assigning them to variables and converting them to series (as shown in my code below):

f4 = (DataFrame extracted from my Postgres database using pscyopg2 and a SQL query) (379, 7)

```
n = f4['id']

wv = f4['watermark_value']

anet = f4['a_net_revenue']

bnet = f4['b_net_revenue']

def adj_calc():

    return anet-bnet-wv if bnet-wv<0 else bnet-wv

f4['watermark_adj'] = adj_calc()
```

I'm receiving the following error: 
"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Through my research I've found that you can run into issues in Pandas when attempting to do calculations directly from the `DataFrame`, but I'm having a hard time finding a solution, or information on which data type I should use instead.

Essentially, I'm trying to create a calculated column on the f4 datafame that follows the logic above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create new Series `s` with subtract and then use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
s = bnet-wv
f4['watermark_adj'] = np.where(s<0, anet-s, s)
```

Or:

```
s = bnet-wv
f4['watermark_adj'] = s.where(s<0, anet-s)
```